# put a new message into inbox and then device manage it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-broadcast

i have an android program, in which i receive a message from the database at the external server on web then i put message in SMS inbox.

now i use system notification like this :

Notification intent :

```
    ctx = context ;
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    syncNotification = new Notification();
    notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,null);
    notificationIntent.setComponent(new    ComponentName("com.android.mms","com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList"));
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);
    contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
```

Notification creation :

```
syncNotification.icon = android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat;
syncNotification.tickerText = ctx.getText(R.string.new_message);
syncNotification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
syncNotification.setLatestEventInfo(ctx, ctx.getText(R.string.new_message),  ctx.getText(R.string.check_your_inbox),contentIntent);
notificationManager.notify(5, syncNotification);
```

and then play sms ringtone:

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(ctx, notification);
r.play();
```

after receive message and put it into inbox, notification shown but when i tap it nothing done.

are there a way that after inserting message to inbox, device show default notification and manage it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in android api 14 and later it is not possible because google prevent .